# Combine two rows with just 2 different column values into one

Tags: sql

I have a table that keeps records of Workplace Accidents. Each `IncidentNo` is supposed to be unique. The organization that provided me the data in such a way that each `IncidentNo` has two entries, one for each gender. Format of the table is something like this. (Table has around 110 columns, I just showed the ones related to the question. All of the columns are `varchar`)

```
+------------+--------+----------------+
| IncidentNo | Gender | PersonnelCount |
+------------+--------+----------------+
|     123456 | M      |            150 |
|     123456 | F      |            100 |
|     789012 | M      |             31 |
|     789012 | F      |             42 |
+------------+--------+----------------+
```

What I need is to combine these columns in such a way that table (Doesn't matter if it is on the same table or inserted into a new one) is something like this:

```
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| IncidentNo | FemalePersonnelCount | MalePersonnelCount |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|     123456 |                  100 |                150 |
|     789012 |                   42 |                 31 |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

I thought to use `Left Outer Join` to insert data to a new table but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: This is a pivot problem: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in appliaction code.

Comment: Not bit on sql but i believe you are looking for a pivot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select incidentno, sum(PersonnelCount) as total_PersonnelCount,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then PersonnelCount else 0 end) as nummales,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then PersonnelCount else 0 end) as numfemales,
from t
group by incidentno;
```

I would calculate the total as well, just to be sure that the total matches the sum of `'M'` and `'F'`.

Answer (score 1):

In its rawest form, you can self join:

```
select x.IncidentNo, 
       sum(a.personelcount) as Female, 
       sum(b.personelcount) as Male
from Accidents x
left join Accidents a
  on a.incidentno = x.incidentno
  and a.Gender = 'F'
left join Accidents b
  on b.incidentno = x.incidentno
  and b.Gender = 'M'
group by x.IncidentNo -- I left this out originally because I'm an idiot
```

Comment: This is either invalid syntax or non-deterministic depending on the DBMS (can't include `x.IncidentNo` in the select without grouping by it). The self join could also cause duplication which might give incorrect results.

Comment: I have removed the downvote because at least the syntax is valid, but this still doesn't produce the correct results. With the example data this query causes everything to be doubled: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a42fd8fec5c550b4610011eac9b5e3fe